# Sorting Order Not Working Correctly

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to change the order of a sorting layer in unity for a 2D game but the below script isn't working for me:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject player;
    public SpriteRenderer deadGuy;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (player.transform.position.y < deadGuy.transform.position.y)
        {
            deadGuy.sortingOrder = 0;
        } else
        {
            deadGuy.sortingOrder = 2;
        }

    }
}
```

The objects have been linked in the inspector window unity before running the game.

EDIT

This is now my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject deadGuy;
    public bool belowTheY;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        deadGuy.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder = 2;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (player.transform.localPosition.y < deadGuy.transform.localPosition.y)
        {
            belowTheY = true;
            deadGuy.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder = 0;

        } else
        {
            belowTheY = false;
            deadGuy.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder = 2;
        }

    }
}
```

bekowTheY is activating if the user goes below deadGuy's Y position so I know the if statement is executing correctly. However the sorting layer is not being changed

Comment: What doesn't work? Does that property change in the Editor but the image is not displaying in the order you want it? How about you comment the code in the Update function put  `deadGuy.sortingOrder = 2;` in the Update function. Select the SpriteRenderer in the Editor and check if the sortingOrder changed the property....

Comment: Looking at the deadGuy object I can see that it is not changing its sorting layer at all. It just stays at 2 (the property set in the inspector window)

Comment: When I said put it in the Update function, I meant `Start` function. One more thing. Remove all code in your update and put`deadGuy.sortingOrder = 4;` in the Start function. I want to see if your code is working. Tell me the value in the Editor.

Comment: I realised that the if (player.transform.position.y < deadGuy.transform.position.y) was not working because deadGuy was a SpriteRenderer and Player was a GameObject. I set both to GameObject and then put deadGuy.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder = 4; in the start function and he did indeed get a sorting layer of 4. However if I update the lines in the code with deadGuy.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder = 0; and deadGuy.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder = 2;respectively, it still doesn't work. If I set a bool I can see that triggering in the if statement though

Comment: `deadGuy` is already `SpriteRenderer`. Please explain why you are doing `deadGuy.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>()`? You mentioned changing to 4 works so that's not the problem Your profile is on this line `player.transform.position.y < deadGuy.transform.position.y` Use Debug.Log and make sure that is what you want.

Comment: use `Debug.log` to see the value , not inspector window

Comment: make sure the dead guy is in the same render layer as player. sorting order only works inside the same layer renderers. But I think there is logical bug of some kind in the code.

Comment: I have edited the question above with the new code

Comment: Both deadGuy and player are on the same sorting layer which is set as "default"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the player object was on sorting order 0 also, so when the deadGuy object was scripted to go to sorting order 0, it was still showing in front due to taking precedence.